# F# convert array to array of tuples

Tags: f#

Let's say I have an array

```
let arr = [|1;2;3;4;5;6|]
```

I would like to convert it to something like

```
[|(1,2);(3,4);(5,6)|]
```

I've seen Seq.window but this one is going to generate something like

```
[|(1,2);(2,3);(3,4);(4,5);(5,6)|]
```

which is not what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Array.chunkBySize and then map each sub-array into tuples:

```
let input = [|1..10|]
Array.chunkBySize 2 list |> Array.map (fun xs -> (xs.[0], xs.[1]))
```

Comment: Note that this solution throws System.IndexOutOfRangeException if the number of items in the array is odd.

Comment: I am having a check for the length being even number so this wouldn't be an issue but this would be a good addition to the answer in case somebody wouldn't do the check.

Comment: @hvester agreed the map lambda can be expanded to create a tuple with an optional second element or some other behaviour as required

Answer (score 2):

@Slugart's accepted answer is the best approach (IMO) assuming you know that the array has an even number of elements, but here's another approach that doesn't throw an exception if there does happen to be an odd number (it just omits the last trailing element):

```
let arr = [|1;2;3;4;5|]
seq { for i in 0 .. 2 .. arr.Length - 2 -> (arr.[i], arr.[i+1]) } |> Seq.toArray
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `Seq.pairwise`, as long as you filter out every other tuple. The filtering needs to pass a state through the iteration, which is usually effected by the `scan` function.

```
[|1..10|]
|> Seq.pairwise
|> Seq.scan (fun s t ->
    match s with None -> Some t | _ -> None )
    None
|> Seq.choose id
|> Seq.toArray
// val it : (int * int) [] = [|(1, 2); (3, 4); (5, 6); (7, 8); (9, 10)|]
```

But then it's also possible to have `scan` generate the tuples directly, on penalty of an intermediate array.

```
[|1..10|]
|> Array.scan (function
| Some x, _ -> fun y -> None, Some(x, y)
| _  -> fun x -> Some x, None )
    (None, None)
|> Array.choose snd
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Seq.pairwise` to turn a sequence into tuples

```
[|1;2;3;4;5;6|]
    |> Seq.pairwise
    |> Seq.toArray

val it : (int * int) [] = [|(1, 2); (2, 3); (3, 4); (4, 5); (5, 6)|]
```

**Should be:**

```
let rec slice =
    function
    | [] -> []
    | a::b::rest -> (a,b) :: slice (rest)
    | _::[] -> failwith "cannot slice uneven list"
```

Comment: This generates the extra pairs (2,3) and (4, 5) which are not desired.